# Storing images of different sizes in a data structure, OpenCV

Tags: c++, matlab, opencv

I am wondering if there is any way to hold (or store) images of different sizes in a single data structure using OpenCV (C++). For example, in MATLAB I can do it by using "cell".

Specifically, I am generating my results which are images of different sizes and it would be grate for me if I can store them in a single data structure. So that, I can use it late on. 
Please note, this has to be done with C++ and OpenCV.

I am thinking to give a try with: std::vector. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Give it a try with `std::vector`!

Comment: +1 lots of functions in OpenCV use `std::vector<cv::Mat>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem lays in the way You think about objects in c++ generally. Matlab requires objects to be of the same size in one vector/array/matrix/however it should be called, because it is optimised to operate on matrices, and those operations are very dependent on dimensions of a matrix.

In c++ the main entity is an object. The most similar thing to matlab vector is an array, like `cv::Mat potatoes[30]`. Yet, even this demands only to be filled with objects of the same class, disregarding the size of those `cv::Mat` contents.

So, to wrap it all up, You have a couple of choices:

- an array, like `cv::Mat crazySocks[42]` - You need to be carefull here, because You need to know how many socks there will be, and You might a segmentation error if You go out of array bounds
- a vector, as suggested by Vinoj John Hosan, like `std::vector<cv::Mat> jaguars` - this is a fine idea, because stl containers can do some nice tricks with their content, and You may easily modify size of the vector.
- a list, like `std::list<cv::Mat> toFind` - this is better than vector if You plan to modify the size of Your container often.
- any of previously mentioned, but with pointers, like `cv::Mat *crazyPointers[33]` - when You have some big objects to move, it's better to move only informations about where they are, than the object.`cv::Mat` does some tricks internally with it's data, so it shouldn't be the case.

Comment: Thanks a lot all of you. I have already tried with std::vector<cv::Mat> and it works perfectly good for my current situation. @morynicz thanks again for the kind suggestions. However, I can not take fixed size array beforehand. But, I like a list idea (std::list<cv::Mat> also. I am going to a give try to it.

Comment: @morynicz: just to be fair, the MATLAB equivalent of general containers are [cell arrays](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/cell-arrays.html)

Answer (score 3):

```
Yeah you can try this

    std::vector<cv::Mat> ImageDataBase;

for(int i=0;i<length_of_imageDataBase;i++)
{
  cv::Mat img = cv::imread("Address of the images");
  ImageDataBase.pushback(img);
}
```